# SphinxQL support for inner join on the same index with subquery

Tags: sql, sphinx, sphinxql

I wish to do inner join a the same index in SphinxQL

```
select * from my_index w inner join 
(select test_id,max(val1) from my_index where match('xxxx') group by test_id) as w2 
on w.test_id=w2.test_id and w.val1=w2.val1;
```

but it's getting syntax error.

my sphinxServer Server version is 2.0.6-id64-release. what's wrong?  does Sphinx or SphinxQL support inner join on with subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered here: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=12237
on the sphinxsearch forum.